# Detect Language From RecognizerIntent

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

i write this code:

```
Intent voiceSearchIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
voiceSearchIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
startActivityForResult(voiceSearchIntent, 1);
```

i want to detect the language of speeched sentence. But when i run the intent it listens only English(US) language:

[image: RecognizerIntent]

is possibile run the Intent in generic mode and retrieve the spoken sentence?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Speech reconition algorithm is designed in the way that it only works with a single language.

You have to create a language detection solution on your own, for example, you can run a handmade phonetic recognizer created with [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net) and apply a classifier on a decoded sequence of phonemes to get a language. There are more advanced algorithm for language identification, see the review for initial links:

http://www.cslu.ogi.edu/HLTsurvey/ch8node9.html

It's not an easy task and it's definitely not robust. It's way easier to present user a list of languages to choose.